# STM32F407 discovery board jumpers

Tags: stm32, stm32f4-discovery

What is the usage of Jumper1(JP1), Jumper2(JP2) and Jumper3(JP3) on the STM32F407 discovery board?
[image: Top picture]

[image: Bottom picture]

Comment: Just want to question the downvotes here. Just because it is in the manual, doesn't mean it can't be here as well. A google search brought me here and probably saved me 5 mins of manual skimming to find the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/70/fe/4a/3f/e7/e1/4f/7d/DM00039084.pdf/files/DM00039084.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00039084.pdf) is pretty clear — JP1 is for measuring the current consumed by the board. It's even labeled "Idd" in the silkscreen.

JP2 and JP3 on the back are just extra ground connections (for scope probes, etc.). You can see them in the schematic diagram.

Answer (score 3):

They use JP2 and JP3 for essentially stand offs because they are the same height as all the other pins. Without them the board would not sit well. Funny design.

Comment: @Amin "JP2 and JP3", or "JPX" for that matter, doesn't refer to the actual jumper shunt/link black piece. It refers to the pins, which is what he is referring to. He is saying if you desoldered the pins JP2 and JP3, the board would sit funny - which it would.

Comment: @DSWG You are right. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @Amin That's okay - that's what this forum is here for :)